# Does it hurt? Vs. Is it hurt?

Tags: grammar

If I want to ask someone if their arm still hurting can I say:

> Is it still hurt?

I wrote the sentence above, but my friend said it should  be:

> Does it hurt?

I know that my friend is correct, but I want to know whether I really can't say "Is it hurt?" at all. Or I can say it but for different case.

**Edit:**

For example, my friend has injury in her ankle. What I am trying to ask is: at the moment, does she feel any pain because of her injury? Has her injury healed or it's still paining her.

And for this kind of situation, which question is more appropriate between the two?

Comment: They mean totally different things. *Is it still hurt?* is asking if it's still **injured**. *Does it hurt?* is asking if you're **feeling pain**. You can have an injury without feeling pain; you can also feel pain without having an injury. Since you say your friend is correct, it's not clear what you're actually asking.

Comment: Can't it be both? For example, my friend has injury in her ankle. What I am trying to ask is: at the moment, does she feel any pain because of her injury? And for this kind of situation, which question is more appropriate between the two?

Comment: You have the answer in the question **Is it**  [your friend's arm] **still hurting?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes your friend is correct, "*Is it still hurt?*" is probably not what you mean to ask, although it is useable English.

> A : "My dog cut it's foot last week" B : "Is it still hurt?"

Not the best English, better would be "Is it still injured?" meaning "Has it recovered / healed?"

"Is it hurt?" is asking "Is it damaged?" or "Is it injured?"